# So, my bad sector count went up from 120 to 736 in a few days, any help?

Tags: hard-drive, disk

Smart says it passed the self test, and fsck doesn't find anything, any help?

Comment: Time for new HDD? Bad sectors is usually a sign of physical wear, there's no magic trick to make it disappear.

Comment: I'm with Artur.  Backup any critical data on the drive _now_ and replace the unit as soon as possible.  It's dying.

Comment: oh im actually the one who posted that, didn't really help